# Refresh the html iFrame on model window

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have iFrame loaded into a model window. In that model window I am loading some URL and that URL contain one button. From that button I am calling AJAX request and update the content of iFrame.

But next time open the same Model window, its remain the response of the AJAX request. But I need to load the iframe src="" content every time when I open the iFrame model window.

I used this code.

**main.html**

```html
<button id="loadiframe">Load iFrame</button>
<div class="model hide">
 <iframe id="ajaxdata_id" src="" width="100%" />
</div>
```

**index.js**

```js
$('#loadiframe').on('click',function(){ 
  document.getElementById('ajaxdata_id').contentWindow.location.reload() 
// **<- above line not work then get the same result next time **
  $('#ajaxdata_id').attr("src", "ajax.html?id=1"); //id is dynamic
});
```

inside 
**ajax.html** content I am doing some data processing part.

```html
<button id="getajaxdata">Get Data</button>
<input id="first" />
<input id="second" />
<div class="ajax_data">
 <span><p id="result"></p></span>
</div>
<script>$('#getajaxdata').on('click',function(){
       $('#result').html($('#first').val() + $('#second').val());
   });
</script>
```

My problem is always ajax.html remain the last response not the ajax.html content.

Ex: when first input value 10 , and next input value 20 and #result p tag html value will be 30.

But when I load iFrame using Load iFrame button that result should clear and should show the content of the main.html.

Comment: Try to get src of iframe and make it empty and then reassign the new url.        document.getElementById("iframe_id").contentWindow.location.href = ""    and then again reset it with new url document.getElementById("iframe_id").contentWindow.location.href =  "YOUR_URL" ; So that i frame url will get changed and it will try to reload it. It might will work for you. OR try to change ifram url to some dummy url and again change iframe src value to yours.